# Conditional Fields

Tags: 7, ajax

I want to add specific number of fields depending on list(integer) field. For example, I have field named number that has 1,2,3,4, and 5 as data. So, when adding a content and the user chooses 3, then three fields that have list(text) field should pop up.

so, this is how the form should look at first.

```
         -
Number: |0|
         -
```

Then, when we choose 3, it will look like this.

```
         -
Number: |3|
         -
        ----------
Field1:|list field|
        ----------
        ----------
Field2:|list field|
        ----------
        ----------
Field3:|list field|
        ----------
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module. Excerpt from its project page:

> Conditional Fields allows you to manage sets of dependencies between fields. When a field is “dependent”, it will only be available for editing and displayed if the state of the “dependee” field matches the right condition.
>
> When editing a node (or any other entity type that supports fields, like users and categories), the dependent fields are dynamically modified with the States API.
>
> You can, for example, define a custom “Article teaser" field that is shown only if a "Has teaser" checkbox is checked.

Comment: Conditional Fields module seems to work for my needs. Thanks!